# Parameter type seems to be wrong type in preference

Tags: magento2, interceptor

I made this two preferences

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" type="Prj\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" />
<preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection" type="Prj\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection" />
```

In Toolbar.php; there is a method

```
setCollection($collection){...}
```

in my custom Toolbar, I specified the collection type to be `Prj\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection`

like that

```
use Prj\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection;
/**
 * @param Collection $collection
 * @return $this|Toolbar
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
 */
public function setCollection($collection){...}
```

But the issue is that the interceptor generated for the collection keeps having the original type `Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\Interceptor` instead of the one I am expecting that would be the one from the preference...meaning I can't access all the custom I made in the Collection preference.

I can't understand what I am doing wrong

This is my Collection custom.

```
namespace Prj\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext;

class Collection extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection {...}
```

Comment: Delete the generated files `rm -rf generated`, and run `bin/magento s:d:c` to compile, so it will regenerate the "generated" files. If you are in developer mode the `bin/magento setup:di:compile` (s:d:c) not required though.

Comment: already made all that sadly^^ the files are well deleted and then generated again...but with the wrong types...